# Python Sorting a file with names and scores

Tags: python, file, sorting, readlines

I currently have some data stored in a file that has a persons name and the score that they got when they played the game.

The data in the file looks like this:

```
Reece 0
John 5
Alex 2
```

I have tried using something like this:

```
with open("Scores.txt","r") as f:
    lines = sorted(f.readlines())
    print lines
```

But that just sorts them by the first letter in each of their names.

My output would need to be like this:

```
Reece 0
Alex 2
John 5
```

It is a relatively simple program and I am using Python 2.7

Any help would be amazing I can also provide any info on my program!

Comment: so you need to sort your lines by number ( 0, 2, 5) ?

Answer (score 2):

A key would work like so:

```
with open("test.txt","r") as f:
     lines = sorted(iter(f), key=lambda x: int(x.partition(" ")[-1]))
     print lines
```

It will be memory efficient as you're creating only 1 list, and as you're iterating only once on the file's lines it will be quite fast.

Overall, I believe it's the fastest and most efficient method.

The full functionality including output would therefore be this:

```
with open("test.txt","r+") as f:
     lines = sorted(iter(f), key=lambda x: int(x.partition(" ")[-1]))
     f.seek(0)
     f.truncate()
     [f.write(l if l.endswith("\n") else l + "\n") for l in lines]
```

Comment: Just to clarify, what this code does is go through each line in the file (**iter(f)**) and tell the _sorted()_ function to sort based off of the lambda (anonymous) function (**lambda x: int(x.partition(" ")[-1])**) which gets the score from each line by splitting it from the name in the line (**x.partition(" ")[-1]**). This will store the list of the lines in the file sorted by score into the variable _lines_ which is then printed at the end.

Comment: I don't believe you need **iter(f)** in the _sorted()_ function but rather you can just use **f** since the _sorted()_ function accepts an iterable as the first argument, which a file (f) is.

Comment: @Mark You're correct, I used `iter()` just for clarification, it causes no overhead at all, and it's really up to preference.

Answer (score 0):

Add [cmp](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted) param to call of `sorted`:

```
with open("test.txt","r") as f:
     comparator = (lambda x,y: cmp(int(x.split(' ')[-1]), int(y.split(' ')[-1])))
     lines = sorted(f.readlines(), cmp=comparator)
     print lines
```

Comment: That didn't sort anything now